# Does anyone know what this smd chip is?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

I have some PCB and on it this chip. I'm trying to figure out what it is. I've searched all over the google, SMD codebooks, datasheet websites and I haven't even found a similar thing

[image: Picture of that chip]

Comment: Welcome! Can you add a picture of the surrounding circuitry? It might help us figure it out...

Comment: Also what's the device it's part of?

Comment: I couldn't find anything on SMT devices, but by searching this I found the Illuminati on the dark web.

Comment: upvote for taking the time necessary to provide a really good picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be an [MP3120](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/EN/sku/MP3120/document_id/1147/) Synchronous Boost Converter.

[image]

Comment: Thank you and thank everyone for the comments. Since I posted this question I haven't logged in into Stack Exchange. I thought that nobody would answer. I guess I'm wrong :D. Anyways, thanks again!

P.S. This board is from electronic door handle made by this company, you can check it out if you want (I'll leave the link here): https://uundz.com/en/electronic-locking-units/door-fittings/electronic-door-handle.html